# mismatched input at line 18 strategy.entry expecting end of line continuation

Tags: pine-script

[Cant solve this error because not sure what error means doing this code for stocks when runs it gives that error]

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/869917755606974545/922914414389239898/unknown.png

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/869917755606974545/922914414389239898/unknown.png

Comment: Please don't post your code as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift your code inside your if block by 4 spaces.

More information [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#if-statement).

Comment: which part to where and thanks for helping

Comment: Edit your question and add your code as text, then I will show you.